# How to match and parse specific info in tags with varying form

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need to parse and process input data pushed into our webservice as (UTF-8) text files from a 3rd party. The input files contain tags in the general form

```
<{ _N ('some_domain_id','this can be an arbitary string',{'a':'b','c':'d'}) }>
-- --   --------------   ------------------------------  -----------------  --
        ^                 ^                              ^
        i need to         |                              this part is 
        extract this      and this (payload)             optional
```

these tags can appear anyway in the textfile, no assumptions can be made about their distribution and whats between the tags. Also `<{`,`_N` and `}>`are present for any given valid tag, but there might be spaces in between without disrupting the values (e.g. between `<{` and `_N`)
With that info, my initial test set was limited and my current implementation is a regex along with a split of the result at the `,`

- Regex `/<{\s*_N\s*\(([^\)]*)\)\s*}>?/g` (Example: https://regex101.com/r/NuJD2V/1)
- Then split resulting match `'some_domain_id' , 'this can be an arbitary string',{'a':'b','c':'d'}`with `str_getcsv($match,',','\'','\\')`
- use first two segments of `str_getcsv` result, dicard other results as they are optional
- After that, `some_domain_id` and `this can be an arbitary string` can be trimmed and processed as needed

The service is up for a while now and i had to realize that although the vast majority of tags is correctly catched, there is a small number of tags that contain anomalies and are not recognized by this implementation.

Caveats (things that can happen in the payload part):

- brackets in payload
- escaped quotes in payload `\'`
- optional modifiers after the outermost brackets of the _N call (see below)

Here are some sample tags i identified that can not be parsed or produce wrong results (even worse than not recognizing).

```
<{_N( 'some_domain_id' , 'this can ( be an arbitary ) string',{'a':'b','c':'d'})}>
```

- Not recognized, note the brackets, they can occur anywhere in the data string, they don't even need to be balanced (Example: https://regex101.com/r/BCiaaj/1)

```
<{_N( 'some_domain_id' , 'this can  be an arbitary  string' {'a':'b','c':'d'})|e('modifier')}>
<{_N( 'some_domain_id' , 'this can  be an arbitary string')|e('modifier')}>
```

- Not recognized, note the extra (optional) modifier after the outermost brackets of the _N element. the modifier can consist of different letters (e,r,w) and an arbitary string argument, also there might be spaces around the chain operator `|` (Example: https://regex101.com/r/XmR2uO/1)

Experimentally, i tried a few other regexes already, but they always fail on one or more of the tags in my extended testset, e.g.

- `/_N\s*(\(\s*(?:\(??[^(]*?\s*\)))+/` - catches the modifier case, but fails on brackets in the relevant string

So my questions as i am not a real regex expert

- is this solvable with a regex and if so, can anyone hint me in the right direction?
- is there a better solution viable in vanilla php 7+ without installing/using some external library

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Well, are there any quotes inside the comma-separated values? Maybe something like [`<{\s*_N\s*\(\s*'([^']*)'\s*,\s*'([^']*)'\s*(.*?)}>`](https://regex101.com/r/7unr35/1) will do?

Comment: If you need to match parentheses or opening/closing brackets, you'll need a tokenizer and context free grammar parser.

Comment: Parsing formats like this is a task ill-suited to regular expressions. I would suggest using a library like [farafiri/PHP-parsing-tool](https://github.com/farafiri/PHP-parsing-tool) and describing your input via BNF/CFG.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : thanks a lot but probably there are (escaped) quotes inside of the values like `this can \'( be an arbitary )\' string' wich would break the regex

Comment: That is not a problem - https://regex101.com/r/7unr35/2

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Whow, thanks a lot - this one passes all my tests. Post it as an answer and i'll happily accept it... Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
<{\s*_N\s*\(\s*'([^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*)'\s*,\s*'([^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*)'\s*(.*?)}>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7unr35/2)

**Details**:

- `<{\s*` - a `<{` plus 0+ whitespaces
- `_N` - tag start
- `\s*\(\s*` - a `(` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `'([^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*)'` - a single quoted string literal that may contain escaped single quotes and other chars (the inside contents are captured into a capturing group #1)
- `\s*,\s*` -  a `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `'([^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*)'` - a single quoted string literal that may contain escaped single quotes and other chars (the inside contents are captured into a capturing group #2)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first
- `}>` - literal char sequence `}>`.

Answer (score 0):

Why could you not just retrieve the parts you need (that being in the single quotes);

```
//example 1
$str = '<{_N( \'some_domain_id\' , \'this can ( be an arbitary ) string\',{\'a\':\'b\',\'c\':\'d\'})}>';
test_pregex($str);

//example 2
$str = '<{_N(\'some_domain_id\'      , \'this can ( be an arbitary ) string\'  ,{\'a\':\'b\',\'c\':\'d\'})}  >';
test_pregex($str);

//example 3
$str = '<{_N( \'some_domain_id\' , \'this can ( be an arbitary ) string\')|e(\'modifier\')}>';
test_pregex($str, '\'modifier\'');

function test_pregex($str, $optional = "{'a':'b','c':'d'}") {
    $re = '/\'([^\']*?)\'|(\{\'[^\']*?\'.+?})/m';
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
    $matches = $matches[0];
    var_export($matches);   
    assert($matches[0] == "'some_domain_id'");
    assert($matches[1] == "'this can ( be an arbitary ) string'");
    assert($matches[2] == $optional);
}
```

Output will be all three cases with no assertion warnings. You can then process what you require further.

Comment: thanks, but as said above input can also contain escaped quotes and it's completely unpredictable whats between those tags. so your solution would also match a huge number of segments between tags... that will not work

Comment: ' it's completely unpredictable whats between those tags' - Now I agree with the other comments. Regex is going to be hell to work with trying to assert all scenarios given - that you possibly have no idea what *could* between the tags.

Comment: generally, after the experiences made with this i would agree, but as i wasn't aware at first i favour a quick replacement that gets away without changing or adding fundamental parts of the service. But see @Wiktor Stribiżew comment, this one passes all my tests ... although you are of course right, i still don't have a comprehensive database on what might come in as input.